# How to replace a string of ID-s with data connected to those ID-s in a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables. First table has a column 'EmployeeIds' which is a string with a bunch of ID-s separated with commas (for example: '4124,2945,2873,4047,3046,4774').

Second table has a these ID-s as his identification (EmployeeID), and also names connected to this these ID-s.

I want a select where I list everything from table1, but instead of the ID-s in the EmployeeIds column, I want to see the names that are connected to these ID-s.

```
SELECT name from Table2
WHERE EmployeeID CAST(EmployeeID AS int) IN (SELECT EmployeeIds FROM Table1)
```

I got the error for this: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '4124,2945,2873,4047,3046,4774' to data type int."

I know the code above isn't gonna give back everything I need because I need to join it with Table1 as well, but I'm working from inside out, and I'm already stuck here.

Comment: it's a bad idea to store a bunch of Employid in a string separated by comma. You can build a query using that string but it's not a good practice.

Comment: I know (also it's bad that table2 id-s aren't even in int form), but we got a DB that we have to use for now, and I can't change the DB, just use some SELECT for now :(

Comment: Try [find_in_set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: what's the back-end database?

Comment: SQL Server 13.0

Comment: Spend the time to normalise the table and current (and future) problems will go away. See comment from @Vasya

Comment: It's **really poor schema design** to put comma-separated data into a column like this. You really want an additional table, with a field for the key from your first table and another field for **just one** employee ID. Then you could have a separate record in the new table for each ID, and solve this problem with simple JOINs. But I know you may not be able to fix (and I say, "fix", because the current schema really is **broken**) an existing system just by snapping your fingers. We're not all Thanos, after all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016, you can do this:

```sql
DECLARE @s varchar(1000)
SELECT @s=EmployeeIds FROM Table1
SELECT name from Table2
JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@s,',') ON value=CAST(EmployeeID AS int)
```